# android gradle plugin version column is empty

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

after I downloaded the new version of gradle 6.6.1 there was an  error showing
"Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle because no repositories are defined.
Required by:
project :app
"
I dont know what to do now. The android gradle plugin version is empty.what do i fill in it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Get the most recent version (binaries are enough) on gradle's website:

```
https://gradle.org/
```

Extract it to :~/.gradle/wrapper/dists

Then go inside this directory until you find the bin version:

```
~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.8/bin
```

And now create a symbolic link:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/gradle
sudo ln -s ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.8/bin/gradle  /usr/bin/gradle
```

Check the version:

```
gradle --version
```

Will give you this kind of output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.8
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-01-08 16:38:46 UTC
Revision:     b7e82460c5373e194fb478a998c4fcfe7da53a7e

Kotlin:       1.4.20
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          11.0.9.1 (Ubuntu 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04)
OS:           Linux **********
```

In android studio, go to Settings->Build,Execution&Deployment,Gradle and change gradle user home to:
~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.8/bin/gradle

Then file->invalidate cache and restart.

Now click on the play button (shift+f10 on linux), on the right of main.dart, it should run smoothly.

[image]